# Does qdel all delete other user's jobs?

Tags: shell, ubuntu, cluster-computing, qsub, torque

I am one person of many using a supercomputing cluster. If I call `qdel all` in the `Ubuntu` terminal will it kill everyone's jobs or only mine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, I believe it only delete the jobs from the same user.

Check out

http://www.clusterresources.com/torquedocs21/commands/qdel.shtml

Comment: Where in the source does it say it only deletes the jobs from the same user? Suppose we're logged in as `ssh -l zurich clustername`, would every job for zurich be deleted or every job on the cluster be deleted?

Comment: If `qdel` is issued by a normal user , it only delete the jobs owned by the user. quote "A batch job may be deleted by its owner, the batch operator, or the batch administrator.". To delete the jobs not owned by the user, you need to be a batch operator or batch administrator.